# Sum per 7 Days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Good day. I'm trying to sum `data` per `7 days`. Please check my script first.

```
select Nip,sum(ro) achieve,FullName 
        from( 
            select a.Nip,b.FullName,
            DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate) week, 
            sum(
                case when DATEADD(MINUTE, -480, OutTime) <=InTime 
                then 0 
                else DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, OutTime) - 480 end)/480 AS RO 
                from DinasHoDetail a 
                left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
                left join DinasHoHeader d on a.KodeDinasHeader = d.KodeDinasHeader 
                left join attendance c on a.Nip =c.Nip and attendancedate 
                between d.startdate and d.enddate 
                where a.KodeDinasHeader = 'DN0000001' 
                group by a.Nip,b.FullName,DATEPART( wk, c.attendanceDate)
            ) q group by Nip ,FullName
```

with my query i get this result.

```
Nip     achieve FullName
1004385    4    RENDY SETIAWAN
```

as you can see from my query. The data is grouped by `week`. When i sum it manually the result is right.

So, my question is, how to change the query above using group by `7 days` instead of `week`. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY, d.startdate, c.attendanceDate) / 7` ?

Comment: @Serg How about `(DATEDIFF(DAY, d.startdate, c.attendanceDate) - 1) / 7`? So day 1 to day 7 will be grouped in first section, 8 - 14 for next section

Comment: will it handle if the attendancedate 1 - 10 ? so  will be like this. Group by 1 - 7, and this 8 - 10 ?

Comment: @YVS1102 yes, it will. Sample demo `select top (10) diffGrp = (row_number() over (order by (select null)) -1 )/7  /* emulate datediff()*/
, [diff-1 Grp] = (row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 2)/7 /* emulate datediff() -1*/
from sys.all_objects`

Comment: @Alex It depends on how the same day d.startdate=c.attendanceDate case must be treated. With -1 first group will contain 0..7 days difference (8 days long)